# How to read each object inside object and move to array

Tags: javascript

I have a requirement to move each object of object into array.
My object looks like below

```
obj = { obj1: {}, obj2: {}, obj3: {}}
```

I need to convert each object into array and it should look like below

```
array[0] = obj1
array[1] = obj2
array[2] = obj3
```

Can someone please help me?

Comment: so `array[0] = obj.obj1`. Your object is defined wrong.

Comment: `var result = Object.values(obj);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## 3 different methods

```js
const obj = { obj: { name: 'obj1' }, obj2: { name: 'obj2' }, obj3: { name: 'obj3' }}

// option 1
const arr = []
for (let key in obj)
  arr.push(obj[key])
  

// option 2
const arr2 = Object.keys(obj).map(key => obj[key])

// option 3
const arr3 = Object.values(obj)

console.log(arr)
console.log(arr2)
console.log(arr3)
```

Comment: I am voting for option 1, because it is most portable and backward compatible (probably would run virtually in any browser). Option 2 use object.keys() declared in ECMA-262 5.1 Edition / June 2011, option 3 uses function object.values() standardized in ECMA-262, 8th edition, June 2017.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values):

```js
const obj = {obj1: {foo: 'bar'}, obj2: {foo: 'baz'}}
const result = Object.values(obj)

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values

> The Object.values() method returns an array of a given object's own enumerable property values, in the same order as that provided by a for...in loop (the difference being that a for-in loop enumerates properties in the prototype chain as well).

```
const input = { obj1: {}, obj2: {}, obj3: {}};
console.log(Object.values(input));
```

> (3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
>
> 0: {}
>
> 1: {}
>
> 2: {}
>
> length: 3

Answer (score 0):

Simple as this

```
let obj = { obj1: {}, obj2: {}, obj3: {}}
console.log(Object.keys(obj).map(k => obj[k]))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const obj = {obj1: {foo: 'bar',foo1: 'bar1'}, obj2: {foo: 'baz'}}

var keyObj = Object.keys(obj);
var valueObj = Object.values(obj);
const newObj = [];
for(let i = 0;i < keyObj.length;i++) {
  var tmp = [];
  tmp[keyObj[i]] = valueObj[i]; 
  newObj.push(tmp);
}
console.log(newObj);
```